# Validate StyleCop in TeamCity

Tags: c#, msbuild, teamcity, stylecop

I'm trying to get TeamCity to build my C# solution and execute StyleCop and fail the build if there are any violations. I want it to execute the same as when you right click the solution in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and then click `Run StyleCop` except that I would like the warnings to be treated as errors.

I've tried the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6370278/413180), however I've had a few problems implementing it.

The problems were:

```
<CreateItem Include="$(SourceFolder)\**\*.cs">
```

was including all `.cs` files in the folder structure and not respecting the individual StyleCop settings for each project (e.g. files to exclude).

Another option would be to have a `build.xml` file so that it can be referenced by MSBuild. However this would mean maintaining the XML file as well as the `.sln` file. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5120423/413180) which meant you could include the solution reference in the XML like so

```
  <include name="MyTopSecretApplication.sln"/>
```

but for some reason it wasn't passing the compiled files when I had my `CreateItem` set as

```
<CreateItem Include="@(Compile)">
```

which should in theory pass the compiled files in and respect include/exclude settings if `condition` was set (as per the below)  (I'm guessing because the XML file including the `.sln` meant the compiled files weren't passed).

```
Condition="('%(Compile.ExcludeFromStyleCop)' != 'true') and ('%(Compile.ExcludeFromSourceAnalysis)' != 'true')"
```

Is there a good way I can get MSBuild to build my solution file in TeamCity, validate that StyleCop rules are followed, and respect the StyleCop rules per project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's how I get this to work in my environment

- Get StyleCop working the way you want to on your dev machine using Visual Studio. I do this using the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/) package but so long as you are getting build warnings when there are StyleCop issues then you're good.
- To turn the StyleCop warnings into errors edit each csproj file and include create a `StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings` element with a value of `false` in the relevant build configuration section, for example I only do this for Release builds. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/24/source-analysis-msbuild-integration.aspx) blog for more detail on this.
- Just get TeamCity to build your solution and as the StyleCop warnings are now errors it will fail the build if there are any StyleCop issues.